# Задержка показа блока

Tags: javascript

Хочу сделать элемент задержки показа блока на 5 секунд.
Тоесть загрузили страницу и через 5 секунд появился блок с линками и т.д.
Помогите понять и по возможности на  примере обьясните)
Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  document.querySelector('#element').style.display = 'block';
}, 5000);
```

```css
#element{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="element">element</div>
```

Comment: Благодарю! Работает.

Comment: @ДмитрийТерещук для благодарности есть стрелочка вверх и галочка возле ответа))